# XSLT remove empty xmlns when using call-template

Tags: xslt, saxon

this is my sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"                       
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                       
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog                      
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd                       
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">
  <changeSet id="1" author="a">
    <createTable tableName="TABLE1">
      <column>
      </column>
    </createTable>
  </changeSet>
  <changeSet id="1-1" author="a">
    <createSequence sequenceName="SEQ_TABLE1" />
  </changeSet>
  <changeSet id="4" author="A">
    <createTable tableName="TABLE4">
      <column>
      </column>
    </createTable>
  </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

And this is my template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"               xpath-default-namespace="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="coreTables"                  select="('TABLE1','TABLE2')"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::*)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="databaseChangeLog">
    <!-- CORE-->
    <xsl:comment>CORE TABLES</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreTablesVariable" select="changeSet[createTable/@tableName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreTablesVariable"/>
    <xsl:comment>CORE SEQUENCES</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreSequencesVariable" select="changeSet[createSequence[starts-with(@sequenceName, 'SEQ_') and substring-after(@sequenceName, 'SEQ_') = $coreTables]]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreSequencesVariable"/>
    <xsl:comment>CORE INDEXES</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreIndexesVariable" select="changeSet[createIndex/@tableName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreIndexesVariable"/>
    <xsl:comment>CORE FOREIGN CONSTRAINTS</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreForeignConstraintsVariable" select="changeSet[addForeignKeyConstraint/@baseTableName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreForeignConstraintsVariable"/>
    <xsl:comment>CORE VIEWS</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreViewsVariable" select="changeSet[createView/@viewName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreViewsVariable"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="createChangeLog">
      <xsl:with-param name="outputFile" select="'core-changelog.xml'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="changeLogContent">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreTablesVariable"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreSequencesVariable"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreIndexesVariable"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreForeignConstraintsVariable"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreViewsVariable"/>
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="createChangeLog">
    <xsl:param name="outputFile"/>
    <xsl:param name="changeLogContent"/>
    <xsl:result-document encoding="UTF-8" indent="true" method="xml" href="{$outputFile}">
      <databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"                               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog                   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd                   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" logicalFilePath="TODO">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$changeLogContent"/>
      </databaseChangeLog>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Problem is that when I'm creating the output file with call of `createChangeLog` template, output elements `<changeSet>` in file have empty `xmlns=""` attribute. Please how can I remove it? Or if there is way how can I define xml header `<databaseChangeLog` with it's namespaces and then tell call-template to use it it would maybe help (but I don't know if it works like this).

I'm using xslt 2.0 and saxon 9.8he

Comment: In your XSLT you are referencing variables (e.g. `$coreTablesVariable`) which are not declared anywhere. Can you correct this please? Thank you.

Comment: sorry, I've copied part of template from another example. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a template that removes namespaces from elements

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

This means, when you set up the `changeLogContent` param like so...

```
  <xsl:with-param name="changeLogContent">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreTablesVariable"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreSequencesVariable"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreIndexesVariable"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreForeignConstraintsVariable"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreViewsVariable"/>
  </xsl:with-param>
```

... It will use this template, and so be set to copies of the node without namespaces.

Firstly, what you should do is change the `xsl:with-param` to this, to select the original nodes, not create copies...

```
  <xsl:with-param name="changeLogContent" select="$coreTablesVariable,$coreSequencesVariable,$coreIndexesVariable,$coreForeignConstraintsVariable,$coreViewsVariable"/>
```

Then, in the `createChangeLog`, if you really want to copy the nodes without changes, use `xsl:copy-of` instead of `xsl:apply-templates` (because `xsl:apply-templates` would just match the namespace-removing template again.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$changeLogContent"/>
```

Try these two templates instead

```
<xsl:template match="databaseChangeLog">
    <!-- CORE-->
    <xsl:comment>CORE TABLES</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreTablesVariable" select="changeSet[createTable/@tableName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreTablesVariable"/>
    <xsl:comment>CORE SEQUENCES</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreSequencesVariable" select="changeSet[createSequence[starts-with(@sequenceName, 'SEQ_') and substring-after(@sequenceName, 'SEQ_') = $coreTables]]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreSequencesVariable"/>
    <xsl:comment>CORE INDEXES</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreIndexesVariable" select="changeSet[createIndex/@tableName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreIndexesVariable"/>
    <xsl:comment>CORE FOREIGN CONSTRAINTS</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreForeignConstraintsVariable" select="changeSet[addForeignKeyConstraint/@baseTableName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreForeignConstraintsVariable"/>
    <xsl:comment>CORE VIEWS</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="coreViewsVariable" select="changeSet[createView/@viewName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$coreViewsVariable"/>

    <xsl:call-template name="createChangeLog">
      <xsl:with-param name="outputFile" select="'core-changelog.xml'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="changeLogContent" select="$coreTablesVariable,$coreSequencesVariable,$coreIndexesVariable,$coreForeignConstraintsVariable,$coreViewsVariable"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="createChangeLog">
    <xsl:param name="outputFile"/>
    <xsl:param name="changeLogContent"/>
    <xsl:result-document encoding="UTF-8" indent="true" method="xml" href="{$outputFile}">
      <databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"                               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog                   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd                   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" logicalFilePath="TODO">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$changeLogContent"/>
      </databaseChangeLog>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That trick `with-param` and contatenation of other variables is super truper. I was using `concat` function but that didn't worked for me. Thank you again.

Comment: Can I have question in this thread? Please can I add attributes to each `changeSet` without breaking namespaces, etc...? I was trying to add another template which will match `databaseChangelog/changeSet` but that didn't worked in all places. I'm mainly interested in output files.

Comment: Yes, you can add attributes. You may need to make use of `mode` on the templates. If you can't get it to work, you should ask a whole new question. Thanks!